# Laravel Eloquent ignores mutator in polymorphic relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model `Image` and a model `Metadata`. `Metadata` can belong to `Image`, but it can also belong to other models, so I use a polymorphic relation:

**Image.php:**

```
public function metadata()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Metadata', 'content');
}
```

**Metadata.php:**

```
public function content()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function setAuthorAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['author'] = strtoupper($value);
}
```

When I want to create an image with its metadata, which looks like this:

```
["author" => "Foo Bar"]
```

I use this code:

```
$image = Image::create($request);

$image->metadata()->create($this->mapMetadata($request));
```

This works well. But when I try to update an image with its metadata, with this code:

```
$image = Image::findOrFail($id);   

$image->update($request);

$image->metadata()->update($this->mapMetadata($request));
```

The data is updated, but my mutator is ignored. In other words, when creating, the `author` is turned to uppercase, but when updating, it's not.

EDIT: Migration for Metadata table:

```
$table->increments('id');   
$table->string('author')->nullable();
$table->unsignedInteger('content_id');
$table->string('content_type');
```

Comment: Can't you use `$image->metadata->update(..)`?

Comment: That produces the error: Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::update does not exist

Comment: Well obviously :D (my bad), how does metadata table look like, can you add migration for that? You could do `$image->metadata->each(...)`. In other words you need to iterate over `$image->metadata`.

Comment: I've added the migration. I'm not sure about iterating - there's only ever going to be one `metadata` model for an `image`.

Comment: @Kyslik Ok, doing `$image->metadata->each->update($data)` works. But this code implies there will be more than one metadata object to update. If possible I'd like the code to reflect the reality.

Comment: Exactly there seems to by something not right, have you followed the [polymorphic relations documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use undocumented [`morphOne`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphOne.html) relationship.

And `$image->metadata->update(..)` should work.